# fork: where does the child start running?

Tags: c, fork

Is the child, after the fork, start the program from the beginning or from the place of is parent?

for example, it this program, is the child start from line 1 or line 3?

```
int i=1
fork()
i=i*2
fork
i=i*2
```

Comment: Child process and the parent process are almost the same after forking, meaning that both child and parent will continue the execution from the line after `fork()`.

Comment: So, instead of taking the exact same time as it took to write this question, you failed to do the very basic printf() debugging that would have answered this question? Here's the code: int main(void) { printf("starting\n"); switch (fork()) { case 0: printf("forked process\n"); break; default: printf("parent process\n"); break;} exit(0); }

Answer (score 7):

> fork()  creates  a new process by duplicating the calling process. 
>   The new process, referred to as the child, is an  exact  duplicate  of
>   the calling  process,  referred  to as the parent, except for the
>   following points: […]

from `fork(2)`

As it is an exact duplicate, it will also have the same instruction pointer and stack. So the child will be right after the call to `fork()`. Now, you may ask, how do I find out whether the current program is the child or the parent? See the manpage on the return value:

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>   and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the 
>   parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

So if the result of `fork()` is equal to `0`, you're in the child process, if its greater than `0` you're in the parent and if its below `0` you're in trouble.

Please note that this implies that every code which is independent of the result value of `fork()`, will be executed in *both* the child and the parent. So if you're for example creating a pool with 16 processes, you should be doing:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    pid_t pid = fork()
    if (pid == 0) {
        do_some_work();
        exit(0);
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        // fork failed
        do_some_error_handling();
    }
}
```

If you miss the `exit(0)`, you'll spawn 2¹⁶-1 processes (been there, just with 100 instead of 16. No fun.)

Answer (score 1):

The fork starts from line 3, the point where the fork occurred.

Answer (score 0):

When fork returns, it returns in both the parent (returning the PID of the child) and the child (returning 0). Execution continues from there in both the parent and the child.

As such, typical use of fork is something like:

```
if (0 == (child = fork()))
    // continue as child.
else
    // Continue as parent.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Child` will be created at line 2 i.e., `fork()` but it will start its execution from the line 3 i.e., `i = i*2`. What confuses me here is your line 4. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: i think, he is trying to ``fork()`` again in line 4, he may have forgotten the brakets.